# Solve system of linear equations to maximize value w/ scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I found how to solve a linear system of equations, but what im trying to do is:
I have 2 variables, `X, Y ∈ [0.0, 1.0]` and what I'm trying to do is:

Solve this linear system of equations in order to **maximize `value`**, assuming that **`x * -1 + y * 1`** is **equal or bigger than 0.**m ***considering that is more important the second equation (the one that I want to maximize the value)***

```
x * -1 + y * 1 >= 0
x * 10 + y * 20 = value
x + y = 1 (constraint)
```

The only idea I have is to do a grid search, but maybe I'll take some time (and it's stupid) to increase X and Y, something like:

```
for x in range (0, 1, 0.01):
   for y in range (0, 1, 0.01):
```

Do u have a better suggestion? **I cannot use the library ortools** The ideal is probably using `scipy`

Comment: are you comfortable with using libraries?  Like a linear programming library?

Comment: why can't you use or-tools ? just curious.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question falls under what is known as "Linear Programming". For a simple system like you have you can often find the solution by manual analysis and a sheet of paper.  However, if you have many variables and many constraints this becomes very difficult.  Since solving Linear Programs is immensly useful there have been implemented many "solvers" that simplify the task.

You simply state the variables, the range you allow them to take. Then the constraints that has to be observed and finally the objective function that you wish to either minimize or maximize.

Then "click" solve and voila. It is normally very, very fast even for huge instances.

(This is a whole field so this is just a bare bones introduction )

Here is an example solving your problem using the library ortools (OR-Tools from Google):

```
import ortools
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

solver = pywraplp.Solver('LinearProgrammingExample',
                             pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)

x = solver.NumVar(0, 1, 'x')
y = solver.NumVar(0, 1, 'y')

constraint1 = solver.Constraint(0, solver.infinity())
constraint1.SetCoefficient(x, -1)
constraint1.SetCoefficient(y, 1)

# if you want to add another constraint like x+y = 1
# constraint2 = solver.Constraint(1, 1)
# constraint2.SetCoefficient(x, 1)
# constraint2.SetCoefficient(y, 1)
#

objective = solver.Objective()
objective.SetCoefficient(x, 10)
objective.SetCoefficient(y, 20)
objective.SetMaximization()

solver.Solve()

opt_solution = 10 * x.solution_value() + 20 * y.solution_value()



print('Solution:')
print('x = ', x.solution_value())
print('y = ', y.solution_value())
# The objective value of the solution.
print('Optimal objective value =', opt_solution)
```

Comment: How can I add another constraint saying that x + y = 1 ?

Comment: Is there any solution (equal to this one) where we don't use this library? Just in case I can't use it

Comment: as long as you don't have to many constraints and variables it isn't too hard to solve by simple mathmatical analysis.

Comment: these are my constraints. do u have any idea how to do it?

Comment: yes, reformulate your equations to form y = ax +b ,draw them on paper and look for which value in your objective function would still fit in your constraint area.

Comment: Do u know this library? How can I do the same u did here but with this one?
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

Comment: yes, i know it. Just give it a try, I am sure you can do it!